# Some problems when trying to implement C code on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I recently started doing some programming with C/C++. I was using Dev-C++ and today
i changed to Visual Studio Code because later on i'll need to work in other programming languages too, like Python, R etc. I successfully installed it and i added the extensions of C/C++ and Code runner. Although am having some problems when i try to run the following two basic programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int x;
    printf("Give a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Your number is: %d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

In the first program i get the following output in the integrated terminal of VS code:

[image]

My first question is a matter of appearance, how can i remove the path that shows above the "hello world" output? Also, notice that i am on the terminal option, if i switch to the output option, nothing is being displayed there, although i have seen in some tutorials that they can display their results in the output option which is more minimalistic than the terminal, in addition it displays the run time of the program which is a nice feature.

In the second program when i press the Run Code button it opens my cmd first and asking to give a number, after i give the number and press Enter i can type the asked number also in the integrated terminal of VS and get the result. Is there anyway to surpass my cmd? I.e. to run the program only in VS without running it also through the cmd? Note that i have already checked the option "Run In Terminal" in the settings of the code runner extension.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So I believe you are on windows, simply installing the extension wont help, there are a few more steps to this.

You'll create a tasks.json file to tell VS Code how to build (compile) the program. This task will invoke the g++ compiler to create an executable file based on the source code.

From the main menu, choose Terminal > Configure Default Build Task. In the dropdown, which will display a tasks dropdown listing various predefined build tasks for C++ compilers. Choose g++.exe build active file, which will build the file that is currently displayed (active) in the editor.

This will create a tasks.json file in a .vscode folder and open it in the editor.

Your new tasks.json file should look similar to the JSON below:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To run the build task defined in tasks.json, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or from the Terminal main menu choose Run Build Task.
You can run your program in the terminal by typing .exe (or .<your program name.exe if you use a PowerShell terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should try to install the Code Runner extension. You will run your future C and Python code easily.